# Swift 3, iOS 10 - Error: Thread 1 Signal Sigabrt (SPRITEKIT)

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, sprite-kit

I have searched all my code and am still unable to figure out why I am receiving the error that I am getting. I also have looked at other threads, and could not find anything newer on spritekit so I relayed on asking my own question. XCode is telling me it is a Thread 1 : Signal Sigabrt on my "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate" in the AppDelegate ***The ERROR:***

```
2017-08-29 23:26:57.775 Flappy Land[10451:1252264] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'Wall' (100 x 1000)] position:{20, -600} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{100, 1000} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d2fcb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109c3e141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d365625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   SpriteKit                           0x000000010a904c95 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 162
    4   SpriteKit                           0x000000010a904bd2 -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
    5   Flappy Land                         0x000000010965bf02 _TFC11Flappy_Land9GameScene11createWallsfT_T_ + 2018
    6   Flappy Land                         0x000000010965ccd3 _TFFC11Flappy_Land9GameScene12touchesBeganFTGVs3SetCSo7UITouch_4withGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_U_FT_T_ + 35
    7   Flappy Land                         0x000000010965cdb7 _TTRXFo___XFdCb___ + 39
    8   SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8f2f1f -[SKRunBlock updateWithTarget:forTime:] + 99
    9   SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8c4ae5 _ZN11SKCSequence27cpp_updateWithTargetForTimeEP7SKCNoded + 99
    10  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8b280b _ZN9SKCRepeat27cpp_updateWithTargetForTimeEP7SKCNoded + 45
    11  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8baace _ZN7SKCNode6updateEdf + 250
    12  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8d0d95 -[SKScene _update:] + 628
    13  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8eeb8f -[SKView _update:] + 984
    14  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8eb5ed __51-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke.322 + 285
    15  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8eaa16 -[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:] + 580
    16  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a8ec1f9 __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 211
    17  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a922ae4 -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 335
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111128767 _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEy + 51
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000011112862d _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 439
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d28fb61 __CFMachPortPerform + 161
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d28faa9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d28fa21 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 465
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d287ba0 __CFRunLoopRun + 2352
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d287016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111759a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010aaee0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  Flappy Land                         0x000000010965f0d7 main + 55
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e29c65d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

***MY CODE:***

```
 import SpriteKit
 import GameplayKit

 struct PhysicsCategory {

static let Ghost : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let Ground : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
static let Wall : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3

 }

 class GameScene: SKScene {

//Variables - Global
var Ground = SKSpriteNode()
var Ghost = SKSpriteNode()
var Wall = SKSpriteNode()
let btmWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Wall")
var gameStarted = Bool()


var moveAndRemove = SKAction()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //Ground Stuff
    Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ground")
    Ground.setScale(1)
    Ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: -640)

    Ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf : Ground.size)
    Ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground
    Ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ghost
    Ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ghost
    Ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Ground.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    self.addChild(Ground)

    //Ghost Stuff
    Ghost = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ghost")
    Ghost.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 70)
    Ghost.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: 0.0)
    Ghost.setScale(2.0)

    Ghost.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Ghost.frame.height / 2)
    Ghost.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ghost
    Ghost.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground | PhysicsCategory.Wall
    Ghost.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground | PhysicsCategory.Wall
    Ghost.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Ghost.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true


    self.addChild(Ghost)


   createWalls()

        }

func createWalls() {



    btmWall.setScale(1)
    btmWall.position = CGPoint(x: 20, y: -600)


    btmWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: btmWall.size)
    btmWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
    btmWall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ghost
    btmWall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
    btmWall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    btmWall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    btmWall.run(moveAndRemove)

    addChild(btmWall)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if gameStarted == false {

        gameStarted = true

        let spawn = SKAction.run({
            () in

            self.createWalls()
        })

        let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)
        let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn , delay])
        let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnDelay)

        self.run(spawnDelayForever)

        let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.width + btmWall.frame.width)
        let movePipes = SKAction.moveBy(x: -distance, y: 0, duration: TimeInterval(0.01 * distance))
        let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes , removePipes])

        Ghost.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        Ghost.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 500))


    } else {


        Ghost.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        Ghost.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 500))



    }


}

}
```

Any help is mucha appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: From where you find Xcode 10 ?

Comment: Asking a stranger to find out why the app is crashing without specifying the actual row where it crashes is not a good topic.

Comment: He/she posted the stack trace which shows where it crashed. That's better than like 99.99% of the people who post "Why is my app crashing?" problems.

Comment: @technerd Sorry meant Xcode 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM: You call `createWalls()` in `didMove(to:)`. You also call `createWalls()` in `touchesBegan(:with:)`. The first time you call `createWalls()`, it adds a node to the scene. The second time you call `createWalls()`, it tries to add that same node to the scene again. You're getting an exception telling you that you're trying to add a node that's already been added to a scene.

SOLUTION: Don't do that. `createWalls()` is clearly meant to be a setup method that only needs to be called once, so make sure it's called only once.

Comment: Worked! Thank you Charles.